# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_name' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] - Angular 8

Tags: angular

Could someone explain what might have went wrong ? 
I am getting this error even upon defining(hopefully):

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_name' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ProjectDetailComponent.html:23)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45294)

in ProjectDetailComponent.html

```typescript
<h5 class="card-title">Name: {{ projectDetail.project_name }}</h5>
```

in ProjectDetailComponent.ts

```typescript
projectDetail: Project;
```

with project as an interface with following properties:

```typescript
export interface Project {
    project_id: string;
    project_name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

meanwhile when i log it in the console, it displays the data as shown in;
[this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnyyx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize `projectDetail` like this:

```
projectDetail: Project =  {
   project_id: null,
   project_name: "",
   description: ""
};
```

or you can use **Safe Navigation Operator** `?` like this in the template ,

```
{{ projectDetail?.project_name }}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hj8fei?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with a ngIf check

```
<ng-container *ngIf="projectDetail">
<h5 class="card-title">Name: {{ projectDetail.project_name }}</h5>
...
// rest of the code
</ng-container>
```

Comment: The `*ngIf` wrapper was also useful.

Comment: Its its useful when you have lots of html elements , the only one check is enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can define `Project`  as a **class** instead of **interface** like this:

```
export class Project {
  project_id: string;
  project_name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Since it's a **class**, you can initialize `projectDetail` property with `new` like that:

```
@Component({....})
export class ProjectDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  projectDetail: Project = new Project();
  ...
}
```

Now you can use in your template without safe navigation operator or some dummy data.
And, it will not give this error

```
<h5 class="card-title">Name: {{ projectDetail.project_name }}</h5>
```

I hope it will help the others :)